# How do you remove certain files from all commits in a Git repo?

Tags: git

I have a lot of delta files (.*~) in a lot of commits in Git, and I want to delete all the files from all the commits.

Comment: I have added this files and commited the code. I want to remove to remove it

Comment: Is the repo published, or just used by you? Do you need the revision history? If not just delete the `.git`-folder and start again. Else check this link https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

Answer (score 2):

Remove from all the commits looks like using [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch .*~' HEAD
```

The [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) has a more complete command:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch .*~'  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

With (as mentioned in this [blog post](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/2-permanently-remove-files-and-folders-from-a-git-repository)):

- `--index-filter` which is similar to `--tree-filter` but does not check the tree, and it goes much faster.
- `--ignore-unmatch` parameter, used to ignore nonexistent files.

That would rewrite the history of your repo, though.
That means any collaborators who would already have cloned said repo would need to reset his/her local clone to the new history of your repo once you `git push --force` it.